# How to keep track of QLabel created in a loop using new operator

Tags: c++, qt, loops, new-operator

I am creating many labels based inside a loop using `new` operator in Qt, something like this:

```
QLabel *p;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    p = new QLabel(this);
    // ...
    }
```

Now what is happening, when I am using `p` it points to the last label in the sequence but I want to use my first label. How can I keep track of every label?

Answer (score 2):

You could store all Label-pointer using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<QLabel*> labels;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   labels.push_back(new QLabel(this));
```

Accessing these pointers can be done array-like:

```
QLabel *first = labels[0];
```

Or by using iterators:

```
std::vector<QLabel*>::iterator itr = labels.begin();
QLabel *first = *itr;
```

Comment: In this context `QVector` might be more idiomatic than `std::vector`.

Comment: I really don't think it's wrong to use std::vector vs. QVector.  Few compilers lack STL support these days; STL was there from the early days of C++; we don't really need a wrapper for different OSs for them; you might one day want to port stuff to non-Qt; and std::vector has an unsigned index, as opposed to QVector's signed indices, thereby supporting half the number of elements.  I use STL where I can, Qt for the rest - but don't use Qt networking for downloads: use libcurl - even on Windows.  Qt, containers reportedly always do copy-on-write, tho.

Comment: Just to join the discussion - the first idea that came to my mind was QList.